# Can't implement modal in disaprove button

Tags: php, laravel

I created a leave system for a project but now i want to insert into the dissaprove button a modal where the admin will give the reason why the leave was not approved,and i don't know how to insert the modal into my system

My controller

```
public function changeStatusToNotApproved(Leave $leave)
{


    $leave->status = 'NotApproved';
    $leave->save();

    flash("Leave has not been approved!");

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

My routes

```
Route::name('leaves.changestatus.approved')->get('/leaves/{leave}/changestatus/approved', [
'uses' => 'LeavesController@changeStatusToApproved']);
Route::name('leaves.changestatus.not_approved')->get('/leaves/{leave}/changestatus/notapproved', [
'uses' => 'LeavesController@changeStatusToNotApproved']);
```

My index page

```
<div class="section-container section-with-top-border">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                @include('admin.partials.panel_heading_buttons')
                <h4 class="panel-title">Leaves List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel pagination-danger clearfix m-b-0">
                    <table id="data-table" data-order='[[1,"asc"]]' class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Tel</th>
                            <th>Reason</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Sum</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th></th>


                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        @foreach($leaves as $leave)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $leave->user->FullName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $leave->tel }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $leave->reason }}</td>
                                <td>{{formattedDate($leave->start_date )}}</td>
                                <td>{{formattedDate($leave->end_date )}}</td>
                                <td>{!!  days_between($leave->end_date ,$leave->start_date) !!}</td>
                                <td>{!! showLeavesState($leave->status) !!}</td>
                                <td class="center">
                                    {{ Form::open() }}

                                    @if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                                        {!! moreInfoButton(route('admin.leaves.more', $leave->id)) !!}
                                       {!! showGeneralButton(route('admin.leaves.changestatus.approved',$leave->id),'Aprovo','thumbs-up','success','130')!!}

                                        {!! showGeneralButton(route('admin.leaves.changestatus.not_approved',$leave->id),'Mos Aprovo','thumbs-down','danger','130')!!}


                                            @include('admin.leaves.partials.modal')


                                    @else()
                                        {!! EditButton(route('admin.leaves.edit', $leave->id)) !!}

                                        @endif
                                    {{ Form::close() }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```